# SXA 1.2 Error Pages configuration

Tags: sxa, error-handling

i'm currently using SXA 1.2.  I have to create 404 and 500 page. do we have out of the box Feature to configure 404 and 500 Page.

In the recent SXA release i can see we can able to configure(see the screenshot below) , but as part of SXA 1.2. i cannot able to find the below feature. So i'm struck here.

[image]

In SXA 1.2 I am able to find Generate Static HTML inside site grouping, I tried clicking , but it didn't generate any static html files.

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you using? If you can get to 8.2.7 then SXA 1.7.1 is available and packed with features.

Comment: we are using sitecore8.2 update 1

Answer (score 0):

We are unable to use the out of the box SXA feature for SXA version 1.2 , So we have proceeded further with the classic asp.net implementation for handling the Error Code
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/customerror-mode-in-webconfig-file1

```
<system.web>
 <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="Contents/CommonPage.aspx">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="Contents/CommonPage.aspx" />
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="Contents/CommonPage.aspx" />
     </customErrors>
 </system.web>
```

Comment: If you have multiple sites under the same instance and you need different error pages for each site, you would need to create some custom pipelines.